# How to install docker on CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, docker, repository, flatpak

Having some trouble [installing](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/) docker:

```
[root@rolly ~]# 
[root@rolly ~]# sudo yum install -y yum-utils
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                            42 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00    
Package yum-utils-4.0.12-3.el8.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@rolly ~]# 
[root@rolly ~]# sudo yum-config-manager     --add-repo     https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
Adding repo from: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
[root@rolly ~]# 
[root@rolly ~]# sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                            22 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00    
Package containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Error: 
 Problem: package docker-ce-3:19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - package containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.3.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.4-3.1.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@rolly ~]# 
[root@rolly ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) 
Release:    8.2.2004
Codename:   Core
[root@rolly ~]#
```

Should I go with `nobest` perhaps?

Comment: Docker does not officially support RHEL/CentOS 8, mostly due to RedHat's flagging of the `containerd.io` package to not run on official deployments.  Your options would be to force install the `containerd.io` package Docker needs on your system or to use CentOS 7 instead which Docker officially supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the latest version is not installable, you can run:

```
dnf install docker-ce --nobest
```

to install another version that is not the very last. A little sad, but it works.